# Homepage setting in Local Group Policy not working on first launch of session

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, internet-explorer

I have a Windows 7 Professional x64 computer I am trying to "lock down" in the absence of Steady State. I have set the policy for the Internet Explorer homepage under Administrative Templates - Windows Components - Internet Explorer.

Since this is a kiosk type computer, the user is logging in with a mandatory profile. My issue is that the first time the mandatory user launches Internet Explorer, the MSN homepage is shown (not the one that is set in GPO). If the browser is closed and then re-opened, the correct homepage shows.

Note: There is no Active Directory, this is set with Local GPO.

The correct behaviour would be to show the homepage I have configured and not the MSN website when the browser is first launched.

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: This happens on first browser launch of the logon session for the default/mandatory profile user. Subsequent browser launches use the correct homepage.

Comment: Do you observe this behavior if you run `gpupdate` prior to first launching the browser? Also to clarify, do you mean the first time the user launches the browser *for each logon session*?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply make the IE browser shortcut a shortcut to the page that you intend for them to reach.  Just change the name to "Internet Explorer" and the icon to the big blue E.

Comment: I think this would work only for the desktop icon, not for the one in the Start Menu or the one automatically included on the taskbar. I am hoping to find a solution that will work for any instance of IE.

Comment: Yes, it would only work for those shortcuts that you replace.  I've done administration for a large organization on mandatory profiles.  This is what we had to do.